# Support old and new URI versions both working without breaking the reverse()

Tags: python, django

How can I support old and new URI versions both working without breaking the reverse()?

For example, I have:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(old_part|new_part)/other/$', 'some_view'),
)
```

In this case `/old_part/other/` and `/new_part/other/` point to the same view but reverse() method fails because it doesn't know how to form link properly.

Also, what if we have `url(r'^(old_part|new_part)/other/', include(sub_patterns))` how can it be handled?

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Still unclear. Do `some_view` behaves differently (emits different content) depending on url?

Comment: For first part of question when url points to `some_view` redirect fits Ok. But I suggested, if we'll have `include(sub_patterns)` in url then what are the working solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you are migrating. This means you don't want old url work, you want it to redirect to new url. Probably with 301 HTTP code (permanent redirect).

Having several urls for same content makes your site harder to use and hurts your SEO. Permanent redirect will tell Google and any other search engine to reindex page with new address.

You can do it this way in Django:

```
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^new_part/other/$', 'some_view'),
    url(r'^old_part/other/$', 
        RedirectView.as_view(url='new_part/other/', permanent=True)),
)
```

If you need to capture everything with a subpath, you can capture url ending and add it to redirect url this way:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^new_part/other/$', include(sub_patterns)),
    url(r'^old_part/other/(?P<rest>.*)$', 
        RedirectView.as_view(url='new_part/other/%(rest)s', permanent=True)),
)
```

You can use `redirect_to` generic view in Django 1.4 and earlier.

Comment: Thanks for your suggetion but as far as I know `redirect_to` is deprecated in django 1.5.

Comment: Also, what if we have `url(r'^(old_part|new_part)/other/', include(sub_patterns))`. How redirect can handle it?

Comment: It's a shame it's deprecated. You can use `from django.views.generic import RedirectView` and then `RedirectView.as_view(url='...')` instead. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't fit all my needs.

Comment: Explaining why do you need two urls for same content can help people answer you.

Comment: Please see my edited question. It's related to include() section in url.

Answer (score 1):

If you want without a redirect, you could try this

```
url(r'^(?P<url>old_part|new_part)/other/$', 'some_view', name='some_view'),
```

Then your view will look like this

```
def some_view(request, url):
...
```

Then call reverse like this:

```
# will return /old_part/other/
reverse('some_view', kwargs={'url': 'old_part'})

# will return /new_part/other/
reverse('some_view', kwargs={'url': 'new_part'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just redirect the old urls to the new ones (with a 301 Moved Permanently).

NB : if you *really* insist on supporting both sets of urls (not a good idea IMHO), you'll have to have two distinct url patterns, and choose which one `reverse()` should resolve to.

Comment: Yeah, it's possible solution but I'm trying to implement it without redirect.